# Google Maps API v3 map renders gray

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've seen several topics on this issue but none of the related questions seemed to bring a solution to me.

I'm trying to display a map using Google Maps API v3. On other sites I work on the code working correct, but in this particular case it just wont work.

Things I did:

- Add an API key (tested it with some random values to it, Google
  alerted directly the used key was invalid then, so that works)
- Instead of including via `//` I tried to include via `http://` since
  this site won't use https.
- Switching with sensor to `true` and `false`
- Tried using an `addDomListener`, also without success.
- Tried to use an event trigger for resizing the map, no luck there either.
- Tried different zooming levels.
- Tried without mapTypeId, when I logged oMap using console.log I saw a Google Maps object with ROADMAP; apparently ROADMAP is the default if none is given.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function render_map() {
        var oCanvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
        var aMapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.2129918, 5.2793703),
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var oMap = new google.maps.Map(oCanvas, aMapOptions);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        render_map();
    });
</script>
```

Console shows no errors or whatsoever. The only output I get is this:
[image: Output]
Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Maybe I'm just overlooking something really silly..?

Comment: What are styling rules for element `map_canvas`?

Comment: What determines the size of the map div ("map_canvas"); same question different words as Anto Jurković.

Comment: [Your code works as is in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DkE5/)

Comment: Why voting down while this is a very legitimate question, providing a perfect explanation on what's the problem. Thanks for your contribution dude.

Comment: Haha came here after a search attempt on Google to find my own question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the script was functioning as expected but due to a CSS-rule I encountered this behavior. In my case it was caused by a CSS rule `div { overflow:auto; }`. Silly.. nonetheless maybe helpful to someone else in the future.

Comment: For me, it was `div { overflow:hidden; }`

Comment: It's an overflow issue, of that we're sure by now ;)